# Change element of vector LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to change an element of a vector using LLVM IR code. The following code:

```
extern printd(num);

array a [1 2 3];

printd(a[1]); # 2.0

a[1] = 10;

printd(a[1]); # 2.0
```

Generates this IR code:

```
declare double @printd(double)

define <4 x double> @a() {
entry:
  %0 = insertelement <4 x double> undef, double 1.000000e+00, i32 0
  %1 = insertelement <4 x double> %0, double 2.000000e+00, i32 1
  %2 = insertelement <4 x double> %1, double 3.000000e+00, i32 2
  ret <4 x double> %2
}

define double @__anon_expr0() {
entry:
  %calltmp = call <4 x double> @a()
  %0 = extractelement <4 x double> %calltmp, i32 1
  %calltmp1 = call double @printd(double %0)
  ret double %calltmp1
}

define double @__anon_expr1() {
entry:
  %calltmp = call <4 x double> @a()
  %0 = insertelement <4 x double> %calltmp, double 1.000000e+00, i32 1
  ret double 0.000000e+00
}
```

That part is okay, the issue is here (`__anon_expr1`):

```
define double @__anon_expr1() {
entry:
  %calltmp = call <4 x double> @a()
  %0 = insertelement <4 x double> %calltmp, double 1.000000e+00, i32 1
  ret double 0.000000e+00
}
```

What I am trying to do is re-insert a value into the vector - this is not working. I suspect it is one of two issues:

1. I cannot re-set an element
2. I am actually re-setting an element in the variable `%calltmp` and not the actual vector.

I would love to know what I can do to fix this.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use vectors here? Your source program says "array". `insertelement` is not an in-place operation; it produces a new vector (which you never use since you don't touch `%0`, which contains the new vector). You can never change the contents of an existing register (that's what SSA means). Also, why is `a` a function?

Comment: @sepp2k I want to use vectors because I think they are more dynamic (not fixed size, ect). I guess the best bet then would be to create a variable instead of a function that returns the vector and change that to `%0`. Thank you for the help and insight.

Comment: That's not what vectors are. Just like arrays, vectors have their size as part of their type - so they're just as fixed-size. What distinguishes vectors from arrays is: They can only contain numbers as they're element type. They're first-class values, meaning they can be stored in registers and passed as arguments to functions (without going through pointers) etc. You can use numeric operations like `fadd` on them, which will then compile to SIMD instructions where applicable (that's their primary purpose). You can't use `getelementptr` on them, so you can't get a pointer to their elements.

Comment: So in a sense, they're even more fixed-size than arrays are because with arrays you can at least get a pointer to their contents and then pass that to a function that can deal with arrays of arbitrary size. You can't do that with vectors. If you're not trying to perform arithmetic on multiple numbers at once, you probably don't want to be using vectors.

Comment: @sepp2k Sorry, I did not know that - thank you for teaching me :). I will consider using arrays instead of vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that you've defined `@a` as a function, specifically one that always returns the value `<1.0, 2.0, 3.0>`. So no matter what you do elsewhere, you'll never be able to call `@a()` and get back anything other than that value. So the first thing you'll want to do is to turn `@a` into a global variable, so you can change its value.

Now your next problem is that `insertelement` does not change the given vector. It can't because vectors are stored in registers and you can't re-assign registers (LLVM uses static single assignment form). So instead `insertelement` produces a new vector with the given index changed. In your code you store that new vector in `%0` and then do nothing with it. Once you've made `@a` a global variable, you can then store the value of `%0` in `@a`. This will fix your immediate problem.

However, as we've already discussed in the comments, vectors aren't really the appropriate choice for what you're doing for several reasons:

1. Since you can't have pointers into vectors, you can't easily write functions that iterate over vectors of arbitrary size.
2. As I already pointed out, `insertelement` creates a new vector with one element changed. This means that the whole vector gets copied. If you create large vectors, that could get quite costly.
3. You don't seem to actually make use of any of the benefits of vectors. Vectors allow you to perform point-wise arithmetic on same-sized vectors of numbers, which will compile to SIMD instructions where appropriate. That's how they're meant to be used - not as general purpose array-replacements.

If you make `@a` an array, you can then get a pointer to its second element and store the new value directly into it. So instead of creating a whole new array and replacing `@a` with it, you simply change the one element that you want to change. That's what you really want.